Volume of any Frustum can be calculated using the Area of its Bases

Source

I have seen proves for base shapes like circles or polygons, but it got me wondering if it's true (or how to prove it) for all shapes.
So suppose you have a closed surface $S_2$ in the xy-plane, and the same "shrunken" surface $S_1$ directly above it at height $H$. If the solid is not skewed, how can one proof or disproof that the formula still holds?
I made a quick sketch for context:


Hint:

It is the volume difference between two homothetic-base cones. The volume of abitrary-base cone was discussed here. Then some basic algebra will lead you to the answer.
More directly, you can use integration
$$V=\int_{a}^{b}S(z)dz$$ where by homothety property: $S(z)\sim d^2$ (explicitly, dimension of $S(z)$ doubles dimension of $d$), $d$ is the distance between $S(z)$ and its homothety center.

